# How to wait until or know when multiple animations are completed in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a code which handles multiple animations. I want to wait until or know if multiple animations are completed. I am currently using `await Task.Delay(1000);` and setting it equal to maximum duration of one of the animations.

**Here is my C# Code Behind:**

```cs
new Animation()
{
    { 0, 1, new Animation(a => dialogControl.FadeTo(1, 1000)) },
    { 0, 1, new Animation(a => dialogControl.ScaleTo(1, 1000)) },  
}.Commit(this, "Animation1");

await Task.Delay(1000);
Debug.WriteLine("Do some task after multiple animations are completed");
```

Is there anyway it would wait until all animations are completed and only proceed then?

Comment: I'm not a Xamarin developer, but since those methods appear to return `Task<T>` you could probably do an `await Task.WhenAll(...)` somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    dialogControl.FadeTo(1, 1000), 
    dialogControl.ScaleTo(1, 1000)
);

Debug.WriteLine("Do some task after multiple animations are completed");
```

Answer (score 1):

from the docs on [Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.animation.commit?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-animation-commit(xamarin-forms-ianimatable-system-string-system-uint32-system-uint32-xamarin-forms-easing-system-action((system-double-system-boolean))-system-func((system-boolean))))

```
public void Commit (Xamarin.Forms.IAnimatable owner, 
    string name, uint rate = 16, uint length = 250,
    Xamarin.Forms.Easing easing = default, 
    Action<double,bool> finished = default, 
    Func<bool> repeat = default);
```

> **finished** `Action<Double,Boolean>`
>
> An action to call when the animation is finished.

Comment: To clarify: by adding `finished` action to `Commit` on the parent animation (the question does `Commit` at correct place; just add that parameter), the child animations will all have finished when `finished` is called.

Comment: @Jason, it does not work, **Code:** `new Animation(){...}.Commit(this, "Animation", finished: delegate { Debug.WriteLine("Animation is completed"); });`. This prints the debug statement immediately even if I have specified some time duration in FadeTo() method in Animation as shown in the question. I have also tried with `Action<double, bool>`, but the same thing happens, It cannot wait until the animation is completed.